# How to pass SSO using selenium2+phantomjs webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, single-sign-on, selenium2library

I am using selenium2 (selenium-java:3.0.1) and phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64. What I am trying to do is getting to a page that needs SSO. When using browser to access the website, it will popup a login dialog to input username and password.

When using wget to get the URL. it stopped at the auth part.

```
test@ubu-test:wget https://www.example.com/details
--2016-11-15 05:18:02--  https://www.example.com/details
Resolving www.example.com (www.example.com)... 10.20.30.40
Connecting to www.example.com (www.example.com)|10.20.30.40|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: /detaisl [following]
--2016-11-15 05:18:02--  https://www.example.com/login
Reusing existing connection to www.example.com:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://sso.example.com/idp/SSO.saml2?SAMLRequest=...something not related... [following]
--2016-11-15 05:18:02--  https://sso.example.com/idp/SSO.saml2?SAMLRequest=...something not related...
Resolving sso.example.com (sso.example.com)... 11.22.33.44
Connecting to sso.example.com (sso.example.com)|11.22.33.44|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://sso.example.com/idp/95wM4/resumeSAML20/idp/SSO.ping [following]
--2016-11-15 05:18:02--  https://sso.example.com/idp/95wM4/resumeSAML20/idp/SSO.ping
Reusing existing connection to sso.example.com:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized

Username/Password Authentication Failed.
```

When using selenium2 (selenium-java:3.0.1) and phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64 with the following code

```
WebDriver webdriver = new PhantomJSDriver();
webdriver.get("https://www.example.com/details");
System.out.println(webdriver.getCurrentUrl());
System.out.println(webdriver.getTitle());
System.out.println(webdriver.getPageSource());
```

The output is:

```
Nov 15, 2016 5:36:07 AM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: executable: ./phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs
Nov 15, 2016 5:36:07 AM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: port: 27571
Nov 15, 2016 5:36:07 AM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: arguments: [--webdriver=27571, --webdriver-logfile=./phantomjsdriver.log]
Nov 15, 2016 5:36:07 AM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: environment: {}
[INFO  - 2016-11-15T13:36:07.904Z] GhostDriver - Main - running on port 27571
[INFO  - 2016-11-15T13:36:08.113Z] Session [76cd8ec0-ab38-11e6-bceb-256426a0974e] - page.settings - {"XSSAuditingEnabled":false,"javascriptCanCloseWindows":true,"javascriptCanOpenWindows":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"loadImages":true,"localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled":false,"userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Unknown; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/2.1.1 Safari/538.1","webSecurityEnabled":true}
[INFO  - 2016-11-15T13:36:08.113Z] Session [76cd8ec0-ab38-11e6-bceb-256426a0974e] - page.customHeaders:  - {}
[INFO  - 2016-11-15T13:36:08.113Z] Session [76cd8ec0-ab38-11e6-bceb-256426a0974e] - Session.negotiatedCapabilities - {"browserName":"phantomjs","version":"2.1.1","driverName":"ghostdriver","driverVersion":"1.2.0","platform":"linux-unknown-64bit","javascriptEnabled":true,"takesScreenshot":true,"handlesAlerts":false,"databaseEnabled":false,"locationContextEnabled":false,"applicationCacheEnabled":false,"browserConnectionEnabled":false,"cssSelectorsEnabled":true,"webStorageEnabled":false,"rotatable":false,"acceptSslCerts":false,"nativeEvents":true,"proxy":{"proxyType":"direct"}}
[INFO  - 2016-11-15T13:36:08.115Z] SessionManagerReqHand - _postNewSessionCommand - New Session Created: 76cd8ec0-ab38-11e6-bceb-256426a0974e
about:blank

<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

So it happens like it just opens an about:blank page and nothing more. Is there a way to input user name and password into popup dialog, and continue the access?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for handling such type of errors, most of the time we get **SSL handshake errors**,i will suggest you to use the following code to handle such type of errors.

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
            caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);                
            caps.setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);  
            caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,**Path**//phantomjs.exe" );
```

//For Handling SSL errors

```
    caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, new String[]{"--ignore-ssl-errors=true"});
```

//To Disable Logs

```
 caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, new String[]{"--webdriver-loglevel=NONE"});

    driver = new  PhantomJSDriver(caps);
```

If you are using WebDriverWait , i will suggest you to disable log from PhantomJS.